# Core Data: how to have a default value

Tags: core-data, swiftui

self learning beginner here.

Although in the xcdatamodel file I have the default value for the attribute of that entity (see screenshot), when I build the preview, the Text("+") isn't there. I guess the countnum attribute in the TargetEntity is still empty.  My thinking is to have the add() run if the attribute is empty. But that doesn't work either. Is there a way to automatically initialize the attribute when the app runs, instead of needing to build a button for the user to press?

Thanks a million

---

[image]

---

```
struct ListView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var targets: FetchedResults<TargetEntity>

var body: some View {

            VStack {
              if let firstItem = targets.first {
                Text("+")
                    .onTapGesture (count: 2){
                        do {
                            increment(firstItem)
                            try moc.save()
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                            add()
                        }
                    }
               }
            }    
}

func increment(_ item: TargetEntity) {
        item.countnum += 1
        save()
}

func add() {
    let countnum = TargetEntity(context: moc)
    countnum.countnum = 0
    save()
}

func save() {
    do { try moc.save() } catch { print(error) }
}
```

}

Comment: Default value? Are you talking about the default value of the attribute `countnum` or a default instance of `TargetEntity`? To me it looks like you mean the latter.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Maybe I worded it wrong.  I want to show that  countnum attribute somewhere else without being in a list (not in the code I posted).   The former seems to me what I need.  So I guess the both? (don't know how to have the former without the latter).

Comment: You need to create TargetEntity objects somewhere in your app, maybe in another view, otherwise the fetch request will never return anything.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you.  Is there a way to do that automatically without the user having to press a button?

Comment: Yes, many ways. You can simply have a function that creates a new managed object. This is where the defaults come in. If you save the object, but have not specified an attribute with a default value, the default value will be set for the attribute in the data store.

Comment: You can call the `add()` method from a number of locations, one is in `onAppear` for the view. It is unclear why you would want to do such a thing though.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried to attach onAppear after the VStack, but it just says expected declaration...  https://imgur.com/a/NRiz1E1

Comment: You put the onAppear modifier on the `body` and not the `VStack`.